# Invalid syntax error for 'pip install --upgrade pip'

Tags: python, pip, installation, upgrade

i am trying to upgrade pip using
`pip install --upgrade pip` but getting error

```
 File "<stdin>", line 1
pip install --upgrade pip
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

can anyone tell me what's the exact issue?

Comment: You need to be using the command line to use `pip install ...`, not python itself

Comment: oh yes. thanks my mistake, well tried in command prompt and now it is showing some error  "SSl certificate". why?. although i upgraded my version by easy_install pip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **SyntaxError: invalid syntax**
>
> is a python error

You are currently running **python shell**:

first:

```
exit()
```

to exit **python shell**.

then you can continue...

Comment: You can also use ctrl+d (in unix shell) to come out of Python shell.

Comment: why it is showing SSL certificate issue after running this command in command prompt

Comment: I am also having this problem and when I try to exit the shell it just closes the program completely. WHERE do I find the COMMAND LINE???